# Change a custom accessoryView in a table to a different accessoryView in Swift 3

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have not seen a Swift 3 solution for this, but I want to show a custom image as a table accessory (an icon on right side of the table). This part works.

However, when this button/accessory is tapped, I need it to change to a different `accessoryView` to indicate to the user that a download has happened.

I have set up a method to do that but no change happens as of now. Here's my code:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var imageView : UIImageView
    imageView  = UIImageView(frame:CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50))
    imageView.image = UIImage(named:"downloadbutton.png")

    cell.accessoryView = imageView

    return cell
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, accessoryButtonTappedForRowWith indexPath: IndexPath) {

    var imageView : UIImageView
    imageView  = UIImageView(frame:CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50))
    imageView.image = UIImage(named:"downloaded.png")

    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
    cell?.accessoryView = imageView

}
```

Is there a better approach to ensure that when the `accessoryView` is clicked, it will turn into the second `accessoryView`?

Comment: A better approach? From what perspective?

Comment: @cristik: Currently, clicking the button does not change the accessory like I intend -- I am new to Swift and believe I have set this up incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the documentation, `accessoryButtonTappedForRowWith` is not called when you set a cell's `accessoryView`. It's only called when the `accessoryType` is set to one of the two "disclosure" types.

You need to set the `accessoryView` to a `UIButton` setup with your desired images(s).

You also need to keep state information in your data model indicating which of the two images should be shown.

Then update `cellForRow` to setup the button with the proper image based on the data for that row.

Finally, in your button handler, update the state for the data for the given row and then tell the table view to reload the row for that indexPath.